# Unexpected tweet text submitted from FF extension

Tags: javascript, unicode, firefox-addon, tweets

I try to tweet from my FF add-on with help of next code:

```
 var hebrewDate = encodeURIComponent(this.hHCalendar.label);
 var author = "@HebrewCalendar";
 var postToTweeterLine = "http://www.twitter.com/home?status=" + hebrewDate + " " + author;
gBrowser.loadURI(url);
```

When I use English only:
www.twitter.com/home?status=Or%20le%20Yom%20Bet%2C%207th%20Sivan%2C%205772%2C%20Isru%20Chag @HebrewCalendar

FF 12.0 shows next text:

[image]

How to solve problem with %20?

When I try to tweet Hebrew text, I see next text:
%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%91%27%2C%20%D7%96%27%207%20%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9F%20%20%D7%94%27%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%22%D7%91%205772%2C%20%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%97%D7%92%20@HebrewCalendar

thank you,
Igor.

Comment: I tried without calling encodeURIComponent: same effect.                    https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=Or%2520le%2520Yom%2520Gimmel%2C%25208th%2520Sivan%2C%25205772%2520%40HebrewCalendar

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're URL-escaping the string twice: once when you do encodeURIComponent, and another time when you load the URL through gBrowser.

Comment: Nope, `loadURI` doesn't do any escaping - the first escaping round must be happening somewhere inside `hHCalendar`.